# Iterative Quicksort

Tags: java, stack, iteration, quicksort, non-recursive

I'm trying to implement a quicksort method that runs iterativly. I have used stack to hold the information. It will also use partitions to achieve this. I know that the partitioned section of code at the bottom is fine, it's only the first block of it that's having issues. For some reason though, my code is not doing what its suppose to. Not too experienced with java, so if anyone sees any errors that would throw a flag it would be much appreciated!

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class QuickSort{

// provide non-recursive version of quick sort
// hint: use stack to stored intermediate results
// java.util.Stack can be used as stack implementation
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] a) {
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

      stack.push(0);
      stack.push(a.length);

      while (!stack.isEmpty())
      {
         int i = 0; 
         int hi = a[i]
         hi = stack.pop();
         int lo = stack.pop();

         if (hi - lo < 2) {
             continue;
             }


         int j = partition(a, lo, hi);
         j = hi + ((lo - hi) / 2);

         stack.push(j - 1);
         stack.push(hi);
         stack.push(lo);
         stack.push(j);    

      } 
         // return;
}

//THIS SECTION OF CODE BELOW SHOULD BE FINE 

// Partition into a[lo..j-1], a[j], a[j+1..hi]
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> int partition(T[] a, int lo, int hi) { 
    int i = lo, j = hi + 1; // left and right scan indices
    T v = a[lo]; // the pivot

    while (true) { // Scan right, scan left, check for scan complete, and exchange
        while (SortUtils.isLessThan(a[++i], v)) {//++i is evaluated to i+1 
            if (i == hi) {
                break;
            }
        }
        while (SortUtils.isLessThan(v, a[--j])) {//--j is evaluated to j-1
            if (j == lo) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i >= j) {
            break;
        }

        SortUtils.swap(a, i, j);
    }

    SortUtils.swap(a, lo, j); // Put v = a[j] into position
    return j; 
}

}
```

TEST CODE

```
package edu.csus.csc130.spring2017.assignment2;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class 

QuickSortTest {

@Test
public void testSort1() {
    Integer[] a = {17};
    Integer[] expected = {17};
    QuickSort.sort(a);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected, a);
}

@Test
public void testSort2() {
    Integer[] a = {17, 5};
    Integer[] expected = {5, 17};
    QuickSort.sort(a);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected, a);
}

@Test
public void testSort3() {
    Integer[] a = {64, 18, 74, 89, 58, 17, 48, 44, 92, 88, 78, 80, 75, 25, 77, 18, 39, 95, 11, 2};
    Integer[] expected = {2, 11, 17, 18, 18, 25, 39, 44, 48, 58, 64, 74, 75, 77, 78, 80, 88, 89, 92, 95};
    QuickSort.sort(a);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected, a);
}


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Why implement QuickSort iteratively, but depend on a Stack class to do it? When you invoke QuickSort recursively, it uses a Stack implicitly, but the code will be cleaner, and probably run slightly faster than your version. If this is some sort of academic exercise to see if you can do it, cool. If you are doing this because you think iterative is always faster than recursion, that is not correct, and you should stick with recursion.

Comment: @ScottK  Since this is a school assignment, I assume that (at least part of) the intent is to make the implicit stack explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Since in partition() `hi` is an index to the last element of an array, in the initial part of the code, the second push should be push(a.length-1), the `last` index instead of an `end` index. Also the if should check for hi - lo < 1 or lo < hi.

After a call to partition, j = the index to the now sorted pivot. The line for j = hi + ... should be deleted, as partition() returns the value to be used for j. Since a[j] is sorted, it should not be included in the two partitions to be recursively processed. The two stack.push(j ...) lines need to be fixed.

---

Example classic Hoare partition scheme for an array of int using a local array for the stack:

```
    public static void qsort(int[] a)
    {
        int[] stk = new int[64];            // stack
        int sti = 0;                        // stack index
        stk[sti++] = a.length-1;
        stk[sti++] = 0;
        while(sti != 0){
            int lo = stk[--sti];
            int hi = stk[--sti];
            while(lo < hi){
                // Hoare partition
                int  md = lo+(hi-lo)/2;
                int  ll = lo-1;
                int  hh = hi+1;
                int p = a[md];
                int t;
                while(true){
                    while(a[++ll] < p);
                    while(a[--hh] > p);
                    if(ll >= hh)
                         break;
                    t     = a[ll];
                    a[ll] = a[hh];
                    a[hh] = t;
                }
                ll = hh++;
                // ll = last left index, hh = first right index
                // push larger partition indexes onto stack
                // loop back for smaller partition
                if((ll - lo) > (hi - hh)){
                    stk[sti++] = ll;
                    stk[sti++] = lo;
                    lo = hh;
                } else {
                    stk[sti++] = hi;
                    stk[sti++] = hh;
                    hi = ll;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```